# ValueError: Couldn't broadcast input array from shape (51) to (51,1)

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting the above value error for the following code:

```
np.random.seed(0);

num_samples=1000;   len_time=50;      dim_data=1;

#The times series X_{1:T} is uniform in the grid [0,1]^2;
#X_train is a collection of such time series
X_train=np.random.uniform(0,1,(num_samples,len_time+1,dim_data));


#Regression coeffecients
beta_1=np.array([-1]); beta_2= np.array([0.5]);

Y_train=np.zeros_like(X_train);


#Creating the model Y_t=X_t.dot(beta_1)+X_{t-1}.dot(beta_2);
for k in range(len(X_train)):
    x=X_train[k];
    Y_train[k]=x.dot(beta_1)+(np.roll(x,1,axis=0)).dot(beta_2)
```

It's showing the value error in the last line of the for loop. I don't understand why this should be an issue. I verified that line in the for loop separately without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

To do broadcasting the dimensions need to be compatible, and you're assigning a 1D array to a 2D array. If `dim_data` is always 1 you can get rid of it, or do `Y_train=squeeze(np.zeros_like(X_train));` to make `Y_train` 2D, so `Y_train[k]` is 1D. Alternatively you can add a dimension to the RHS of the equation so it's also 2D like this:

```
Y_train[k]=(x.dot(beta_1)+(np.roll(x,1,axis=0)).dot(beta_2))[:,None]
```

In which case the RHS will be added to each column of `Y_train[k]` if `dim_data` is > 1. This is what is meant by 'broadcasting' in numpy.

Comment: For me dim_data is a variable and I do not know before hand if it's always 1 or not.

Comment: Perhaps `Y_train[k] = atleast_2d(x.dot(beta_1)+np.roll(x,1,axis=0)).dot(beta_2)).T`?

Comment: I understood my mistake. Thanks. If dim_data is not equals one beta_1 and beta_2 will be matrices and I can change the dimension of Y accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the RHS of your calculation  produces a (51,) 1d array, but the LHS slot is (51,1), a 2d.  Broadcasting can change a (51,) to (1,51), but not to (51,1).

> It that's not clear, I'd suggest a review of basic numpy documentation.  Understanding dimensions, shapes and broadcasting are fundamental.

The next step is understanding where the dimensions come from.

`X_train` is created as `(num_samples,len_time+1,dim_data)`, and `Y_train` copies.  So `Y_train[k]` has shape `(len_time+1,dim_data)` - hence the 2d (51,1).  Same for `x`

The RHS has 2 terms that are broadcasting compatible, and produce (51,) because of the `dot` summation.

```
x.dot(beta_1)+(np.roll(x,1,axis=0)).dot(beta_2)
(51,1) dot ((1,) => (51,)
```

To really fix this you need to work with a `dim_data` that is larger than 1.  With a 1 you could just squeeze out the dimension, but that won't help if that 3rd dimensions is larger.

Why is `Y_train` initialed to 3d, when the RHS removes that last dimension from `x` with the the `dot` products?